# Passing a list as an attribute in C ++

Tags: c++, dll, cen-xfs

I need to create a list of `LPSTR` and put this in a`LPSTR` attribute of a struct.

```
typedef struct _wfs_pin_caps
{
...
LPSTR               lpszExtra; //This attribute should receive
} WFSPINCAPS, * LPWFSPINCAPS;
```

I need something of this kind.

```
WFSPINCAPS PinCapabilities;

list<LPSTR> Keys;
Keys[0] = (LPSTR) "value=key";
Keys[1] = (LPSTR) "value1=key1";
Keys[2] = (LPSTR) "value2=key2";

PinCapabilities.lpszExtra = Keys;
```

I need to pass lists with VARIOUS values...

Comment: If you have to cast to get a string to work, it's a sign you're doing something dangerous and wrong. In this case, you're casting away constness and it isn't even clear from a glance that you're doing so.

Comment: really does not make sense to store a pointer to a `std::list` in a `LPSTR`.  Why not have a `std::list*` in the `struct`?

Comment: The final program wants multiple values, like an array

Comment: @MatheusCardozo Please read my update, I thought it was clear.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi ok man...I will test

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just do this

```
struct _wfs_pin_caps {
    // ... other fields ...
    std::list<const LPSTR> lpszExtra;
};
list<const LPSTR> &extra(PinCapabilities.lpszExtra);
extra.push_back(TEXT("value1=key1"));
extra.push_back(TEXT("value2=key2"));
// ... more items ...
extra.push_back(TEXT("valueN=keyN"));
```

Read about [The `TEXT` macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374074(v=vs.85).aspx) so you don't do that awkward cast at all, which is wrong BTW.

Note: You should probably need `std::vector` instead, read their documentation to decide.

Comment: Hey guy, i need to pass lists with VARIOUS values

Comment: Presumably, the struct is not the OP's code to change. `TEXT` is also not for `LPSTR`, it's for `LPTSTR`. If the string were to change to a wide string, `TEXT` would start producing a compiler error. T-strings in general are rather dated nowadays in any case. `TEXT` also doesn't fix the cast, as `TEXT` is unrelated to const correctness. As for `const`, it won't work because `LPSTR` is a `char*`, making `const LPSTR` a `char* const`. The more common spelling is `LPCSTR`.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi guy, i need use this struct: typedef struct _wfs_pin_caps
{
...
LPSTR               lpszExtra; //This attribute should receive
} WFSPINCAPS, * LPWFSPINCAPS;

Comment: You can't, create a list of structs then.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure cen-xfs thing so having just C++ knowledge is not enough.
All lpszExtra fields of XFS structures are special formatted C strings.

So the correct way to fill lpszExtra field of a xfs capabilities struct is to use double NULL terminated and NULL separated string.
And as all of these fields are key value pairs so the format is:
"key1=value1\0key2=value2\0...\0keyN=valueN\0\0"
Note here "keyX" does NOT mean PINPAD key definition, but the way all XFS lpszExtra field data is formatted so first key_name =-sign key_value.

How you handle those strings are up to you, but I like to use normal newlines instead of '\0' as key-value pair separators and then just convert to/from that to the XFS specific NULL char separated and double NULL terminated format.

That way you can use normal C string methods for manipulation in your own code.

Easy conversion is allocate memory, make copy and swap '\n' to '\0' and '\0' to "\0\0" while copying from C string to XFS and reverse when converting from XFS to C string.

Note this is aplicable only for those lpszExtra fields in XFS structs.